# Regexp for preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I have strings like this (some examples):

```
 F7998FM3213/02F
 J442554NM/05
 K439459845/34D
```

I need to use PHP with `preg_replace` and regular expressions to delete all non-numeric characters in any string, after the forward-slash, '/'.

For example the codes above would look like this afterwards:

```
F7998FM3213/02
J442554NM/05
K439459845/34
```

Comment: Very interesting challenge!

Comment: Will the non digit characters be only at the end? or can they be anywhere?

Comment: Non digital characters can be anywhere, but I need to remove it only after "/". String can be like K439459845/X32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all `\D` anywhere after a `/` you could replace:

```
(?:/\K|\G(?!^))(\d*)\D+
```

with `$1`. Like:

```
preg_replace(',(?:/\K|\G(?!^))(\d*)\D+,', '$1', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
$subject = <<<LOD
F7998FM3213/02F
J442554NM/05
K439459845/34D
K439459845/34D34
LOD;

echo preg_replace('~^[^/]*+/\K|[^\d\n]++~m', '', $subject);
```

explanation:

The regex is an alternation between two things:

1. You match the begining until you encounter `/` included
2. the part after the `/` that is all that is not a digit or a new line one or more times

Since the begining of the string is checked at first, all non digit characters are removed **after** the `/`

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for readability, something like this would be perfect:

```
$parts = explode("/",$line,2);
$parts[1] = preg_replace("/\D/","",$parts[1]);
$output = implode("/",$parts);
```

However, for conciseness and based entirely on the examples you have given, try this:

```
$output = preg_replace("/\D+$/","",$input);
```

This will strip any non-numeric characters from the end of the string, which seems to be what you're after based on your examples.